# Palatinox package

Tags: fonts, packages

`palatinox.sty` on CTAN states that it provides Linotype Palatino. But this font is not free, is it? How this could be possible?

Comment: It provides support for the font, where's the problem? The font itself is not included.

Comment: @egreg Did I misunderstand the LaTeX font system or *.tfm, *.afm, *.enc and *.vf files represent the actual font?

Comment: No, they just provide the metric files.

Comment: @egreg so the font must come as a .ttf?

Comment: It should be Type1, but also TrueType could be managed for.